# Upgrade to 12.10 failed, system freezes

Tags: 12.10, freeze

After upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10 last night, I received several error messages. I try to send reports for the Ubuntu teams, and after the upgrading finished, I realise it's a complete failure. When I boot the computer, I get to the desktop with the icone but then I cannot do much as it is all frozen. I start to freeze, nothing can be done for 3-4 minutes, then all icones and bars dissappear and reappear, it seems like it unfreezes but refreezes instantly. However I can use the terminal, so does anyone have an idea how to reinstall or fix this through the terminal or whatever?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: Have you tried running the installation again, to see if the problem is persistent? It may just have been something going wrong that one time?

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing a fresh install (assuming you don't have important files on the drive) as opposed to an upgrade.  In some cases, upgrades can create problems:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1973093

http://ubuntuper.wordpress.com/2010/09/17/fresh-install-vs-upgrade-benefits-and-negatives-with-both/

If you can use the terminal without problems, you could try getting updates.